# Room Finder in Outlook doesn't consistently show up. How does it work?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

The Room finder dock on the right hand side of a new meeting doesn't show up for me consistently.  Sometimes it's there and sometimes it's not.  I thought maybe it was an Exchange connectivity issue but other people in my team will have it when I don't.

Comment: I'm using office oulook 2013

Comment: I would like room finder to be constantly visible or at least the "room finder" button to be visible

Comment: I get this on Outlook 2016

Comment: Since there is no solution on this one yet (since 4 years now) I've done a new Post for it that summarizes everything: https://superuser.com/questions/1378703/oulook-16-room-finder-button-missing-not-working-after-adding-it-a-second-t

Answer (score 2):

What version of MS Outlook are you using? Could you also describe what behavior are you trying to achieve? Do you want the  Room Finder constantly hidden or constantly shown?

You might want to tweak some registry entries and see the result.

In Outlook 2010:

> Key:
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Preferences

In Outlook 2013:

> Key:
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Preferences

If `RoomFinderShow` is `0` in the previously mentioned policy hive, the Room Finder behaves the following ways when you start Outlook:

- The Room Finder is not shown by default on the Appointment tab.
- You can manually enable the Room Finder on the Appointment tab.
- If you open a new meeting form after enabling the Room Finder in another meeting form, the   Room Finder is not shown by default on the Appointment tab of the new meeting form.
- If you manually enable and then disable the Room Finder on the Appointment tab, nothing is written into the registry.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2673231

Comment: The 1st 2 items in the bullet list seem to be in conflict. If the button isn't in appt tab the how can you enable room finder. No?

Comment: Thanks for including the source.  I'd looked at that page already and it doesn't explain why sometimes the Room Finder button doesn't show up.

Comment: I would assume that your Microsoft Exchange Add-in is not running. Next time when you don't see Room Finder button, please check if the add-in is running (File->Options->Add-ins)

Comment: The answer above is only relevant to the actual Room Finder window/section visibility. Not the button. If the button is missing, then this answer and all the info in the link provided does not apply

Comment: Hmm, i;ll check for the add-in next time it happens and report back :)

Comment: After a number of weeks, it happened again.  I looked and the Microsoft Exchange Add-in is active.

Comment: At first, I also thought this is because of the Exchange Add-In.

But first thing is: I can't activate it. It looks like it does it, but on next start, it's disabled again.

Also: In the Citrix-Environment, I also have Outlook 2016. In this environment the Add-In is active, and I still don't have the Room Finder. Same for three of my colleagues and my manager. However, another regular user does have the button, and it works just fine...
I do not understand this...

Comment: Since there is no solution on this one yet (since 4 years now) I've done a new Post for it that summarizes everything: https://superuser.com/questions/1378703/oulook-16-room-finder-button-missing-not-working-after-adding-it-a-second-t